# puts and printf do not give out full text (text containing CJK characters), when the text is read from a local file, on Windows, MSVC

Tags: c, windows, encoding

The text contains:

```
..... (some characters can't be posted on SO)


xxxxxxxx=xxx xxxxxxx=xxxxx://xxx..xxx/xxxxx/xx9528994
```

(for full text & data please see https://github.com/ggaarder/snippets/raw/master/x.txt)

which is ended in `xxxxx://xxx..xxx/xxxxx/xx9528994`, however, when reading it then `puts`, it only gives out

```
..... (some characters can't be posted on SO)


xxxxxxxx=xxx xxxxxxx=xxxxx:/
```

which only prints to `xxxxx:/`, and `/xxx..xxx/xxxxx/xx9528994` is missed.

Code to test:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char s[30000];
    FILE *f = fopen("x.txt", "r");
    
    fread(s, sizeof(s), 1, f);
    puts(s);

    return 0;
}
```

The buffer size 30000 is adequate. `x.txt` is 1049 bytes.

You can download `x.txt` at https://github.com/ggaarder/snippets/raw/master/x.txt, for convenience I have packed everything to https://github.com/ggaarder/snippets/raw/master/foo.zip.

It will be very kind of you to download and take a look of `x.txt`, since most part of it can't be posted on SO because of the special characters, including some CJK.

Attempts:

1. The whole file is read properly. @pmg notices that `fread` returns zero, while @Someprogrammerdude points out that if `fread`'s size and count arguments are swapped `fread` returns `1049`, and this supports the guess.
2. If the CJK letters are removed, the output will be totally OK. So I think there is no '\0' in the middle.
3. By adding

```
ret = puts(s);
printf("\nret: %d, %s", ret, strerror(errno));
```

We will get `ret: 0, No error`. `puts` return zero and there's nothing in errno.

5. You may notice that there's a heading `\n` in `3.`. Yes, `puts` doesn't gives out the newline as usual - does this suggest that `puts` failed?
6. But why does it returns zero and there's nothing in `errno`?
7. May it be related to Windows NT `cmd`? Maybe some special terminal control letters are unintentionally out.
8. Reading by `rb` is the same. `x.txt` is an XML text, just for convenience I removed part of it that are the irrelevant, so it looks like spam.

---

I guess this is just yet another encoding issue, plus some magical secret Windows commandline control sequence .... I'm not taking it. I will just erase all non-ASCII characters.

Comment: This won't compile due to the unbalanced quotes: `FILE *f = fopen(x.txt", "r");`. Please provide your **actual** code.

Comment: One *major* problem (that leads to *undefined behavior*) is that `fread` reads raw data, not strings. That means the contents of the array `s` will *not* be a null-terminated byte string (which is what `puts` is expecting).

Comment: @r3mainer Sorry, that was removed accidentally.

Comment: I'm also not sure how `fread` handles things like newline translations (e.g. `\n` to `\r\n` or the opposite) of files open in text-mode. For text file you really should be using text-reading functions (like e.g. `fgets`).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for your advice. The text contains some CJK letters, and can't be posted here. If the CJK letters are removed, the output will be totally OK, so I think there is no '\0' in the middle.

Comment: What is the actual size of the file you attempt to read? What does browsing to it and checking its properties report as its size? CJK character are probably stored as UTF-8, which is a *multi-byte* encoding scheme, so each character is probably using two or more bytes (plus you might need to account for the newline issues).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That's 1049 bytes.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the size. It's kind of crucial to know that the buffer size really is "adequate".

Comment: Now you need to edit your program to check what `fread` [*returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread#Return_value). You should also be using this value to add the null-terminator to the string. I also suggest you reverse the size and count arguments, the first of them is the size of each "element", and since you're reading bytes it should be `1`. The second size argument is the number of "elements" you want to read, which is up to `sizeof s` elements.

Comment: In text mode Windows, carriage return-line feed (CRLF) pairs read by [`fread()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fread?view=vs-2019) are replaced by single line feed (LF) characters.

Comment: The files contains not only UTF8 chars. Give a look to the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48730724/how-am-i-allowed-to-workaround-dos-functions-that-used-strings-containing-accent

Comment: Try, if you haven't already, `FILE *f = fopen("x.txt", "rb");` and `unsigned long len = fread(s, sizeof(s), 1, f); if (len == 0) perror("fread too little");`

Comment: @pmg Wow, it says `read 0 bytes from the file.`! And `fread too little: No error`.

Comment: Just means [`fread()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fread.html) was unable to read `1` block of `sizeof s` bytes before `EOF` was signalled

Comment: If the file is `1049` bytes, and `fread` returns `1049` with the size/count arguments switched, then you have successfully read the whole file into the array. Now you need to null-terminate the array, so it's a proper string that can be used as such. And if it still doesn't work, you need to use a hex-editor to look at the raw bytes of the input file, to make sure there's no zero bytes in it.

Comment: Other than using the correct order of arguments in `fread`, you can also try scanning the file contents in binary mode. In text mode, the low I/O layer (i.e. the underlying `_read` call) interprets Ctrl+Z (0x1A) as EOF. If there's no Ctrl+Z in the file contents read in binary mode, then you should switch back to using text mode. If the file contents are UTF-8 encoded, then you should use `"r,ccs=UTF-8"` for the mode. This will decode the text to `wchar_t`, so in this case an `fread` uses an element size of 2 bytes, i.e. `sizeof(wchar_t)`, and the buffer should be a `wchar_t` array.

Comment: With the file contents as a wide-character string, write it to stdout with `_putws` instead of `puts`, and make sure stdout is in UTF-16 mode via `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT)`. If it's a console, UTF-16 mode causes the low I/O `_write` to call wide-character `WriteConsoleW` instead of `WriteFile`. This is the only way to reliably write Unicode text to the Windows console, including versions prior to Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just yet another encoding issue happening everyday. Just `SetConsoleOutputCP(65001)` or `/utf-8` or set execution code page in #pragma and everything will be fine.

Answer (score 2):

The order of the "size" and "count" arguments to [`fread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) is crucial.

The first argument is the "element" size, and the second argument is the number of elements to attempt to read.

In the case of a text file, the element size is a single character, usually a single byte. The number of elements to attempt to read is the size of the destination array.

So your call should be

```
fread(s, 1, sizeof s, f);
```

instead.

---

What happens now when you have the opposite is that you say that the "element" size is `30000` bytes, and that `fread` should read one such element. Since the size of the file is less than `30000` bytes, it just can't read even a single element, and returns `0` to indicate it.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this and the output is the same.

Comment: wait, though the output is the same `fread` returns different values. This gives out a non-zero.

Comment: @Aoyama And that means `fread` have actually succeeded in reading your file. The value it returns is the number of "elements" (character/bytes) it has managed to read.

Answer (score 0):

1. open the file in binary mode
2. switch arguments and check the return value of `fread()`.

---

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 int main(void) {
     char s[30000];
     FILE *f = fopen("x.txt", "rb");                // binary mode
     unsigned long len = fread(s, 1, sizeof(s), f); // switch args, check value
     if (len < 1) {
         perror("bad fread");
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }
     s[len] = 0;                                    // properly terminate s
     puts(s);

     return 0;
 }
```